# How to convert italic font to normal font in pdf using some library?

Tags: pdf, fonts, imagemagick, ghostscript

Is there any way to convert Italic font, Bold font in my pdf to normal font using some library like Imagemagick or GhostScript etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the answer is 'no' though there are several levels of caveat in there.

The most common scenario for a PDF file is that it contains an embedded font, and that font is subset. In this case the font will use a custom Encoding, so that when you see 'Hello' on your monitor, the actual character codes might  be 'Axtte' or similar gibberish. **If** the font also contain a ToUnicode table you could, technically, create an embedded subset of the regular font from the same family as the bold or italic and embed that, and it would work. This would be an immense amount of work.

If the font isn't subset then it may not contain a custom Encoding, which would make that task easier, because you wouldn't have to re-encode the replacement.

If the font isn't embedded, then you need only change the font name in the Font object, because the PDF consumer will have to find a substitute anyway.

Note that, because PDF is a binary format, with an index (xref) containing the offset of every object in the file, any changes will mean that the xref table has to be reconstructed, again a considerable task.

I'm not aware of any tools which would do any of this for you automatically, you'd have to write your own, though some things could be done automatically. MuPDF for example will 'fix' a PDF file which has an incorrect xref table for you.

And even after all that, the likelihood is that the spacing would be different for the italic or bold font compared to the regular font anyway, and would look peculiar if you replaced them with a regular font.

So, fundamentally, no.

Answer (score 0):

In low-level PDF you can apply some rendering flags in front of a text stream. Like the "Rendering Mode" `Tr` operation. For instance, in this scenario you can include the rendering of text outline and increase outline drawing width with the command sequence `0.4 w 2 Tr` which will cause Normal text to become more "bold" (There are other better ways to accomplish this using the Font Description dictionary). However, one can also employ this tactic to slim down bold text using a clipped thicker outline, but this may not be ideal.

As for italic, most fonts contain a metric indicating their italic angle, and you can use this to add a faux italic using a shear CTM transformation matrix with the `cm` operation. Once again, this may work better to add an italic shear, but may also have some success in removing it.

See the [PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf).

This will require a library with lower level PDF building and you would have to do it manually, but it is possible technically.